Line spacing on Classic Email templates for PDF
I've been working on a template in Classic Email Templates for a PDF for postal mail receipts. The line spacing is perfect everywhere except with the mailing address dynamic fields. No matter what I do, the lines are double-spaced (I want them single-spaced, like you always see on any official letter you get in the mail). This doesn't happen anywhere else in the template, including other lines with dynamic fields.
I've tried adding "line-spacing" CSS in both div and paragraph (separately - neither one worked), and I've tried adding "!important" to said CSS. I've tried using ONLY div with no paragraph tags. I've tried using separate paragraphs with no br tags. Not only do none of them work, they don't seem to have any effect at all. Because it's a PDF, I can't use "inspect" like you could with an email. The spacing looks correct in the template after I save it and before I actually run a copy.
Any ideas?
